# Unable to upgrade to Pro Account - Paypal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to use Direct Pro method. Following an example I am able to post and receive the following response.

```
TIMESTAMP=2013%2d08%2d22T06%3a16%3a23Z&CORRELATIONID=c57ab5b2a4ab5&ACK=Failure&VERSION=58%2e0&BUILD=7333778&L_ERRORCODE0=10501&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Invalid%20Configuration&L_LONGMESSAGE0=This%20transaction%20cannot%20be%20processed%20due%20to%20an%20invalid%20merchant%20configuration%2e&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error&AMT=20%2e00&CURRENCYCODE=USD
```

Again searching throuh Stackoverflow for the above error, it seems like sandbox merchant account is business account and I need to convert it to pro. Again tried and now I am stuck at following error.

[image]

Any idea why this error is coming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

U cannot upgrade the US sanbox test account to pro. Just create business account(test account) with country as UK and then upgrade it to pro.

Comment: Thanks a ton.. It was real frustration for me for last few days. I am suprised why paypal couldn't say the same thing instead of that shitty "something went wrong error"

Comment: i dont know why paypal doesn't include it in the doc. But there's you guys. Awesome !

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error for both US and UK accounts. However, after logging-out and back in, the account type switched to Business-Pro.